# How to install snap packages

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I need to install Azure IoT Edge on Ubuntu Core, which uses snap as packet manager.

I found https://launchpad.net/azure-iot-gateway-snap which seems to be the snap version for Azure IoT Edge, but now I don't know how I can install it.

How can I install it ? Do I need to compile it from sources ? If yes, how ?

It's the first time I need to use snap as packet manager, I usually always used apt and I'm a bit lost about what I need to do with this website. I didn't find any download link or anything.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: `snap install <program>`  (`snap` in lieu of `apt`)

Comment: You say you want azure iot edge but the link is for azure iot gateway?

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I didn't think it was that simple..

Comment: @dsSTORM yes the name can be confusing but i think it's the correct package : https://launchpad.net/~aziot/+snap/azure-iot-edge

Comment: There is also azure-iot-gateway: https://snapcraft.io/azure-iot-gateway

Answer (score 0):

`snap` was modelled after `apt` in command structure, so

```
sudo snap install <snap.package>
```

(ie. snap in lieu of `apt`)

An example I found on a Ubuntu/Canonical web site is (*it shows installing MAAS as snap right at the top* from https://docs.maas.io/devel/en/installconfig-snap-install with options 'stable' to enforce a specific branch to be used, and 'devmode' to reduce confinement so the snap can use more system resources; options may not be required like this example)

```
sudo snap install maas --devmode --stable
```

Basic tutorials can be found at

> https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#0
>   https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers